# Error f1026 when compiling a project in Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, android-sdk-2.3

When building the project, the error File not found 'Not found' appears. This error appears even when compiling an empty FMX project. Android SDK installed not from the box, but through Android Studio. I also tried updating and installing different versions of the SDK.

Comment: @FreddieBell test -> text

Comment: Remote viewing is having trouble seeing your screen at present. Can you post the full text of the error message you received.